# SCWaveFormView does not show waveform

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, calayer, waveform

I am developing an iOS app, in objective c.

Where I am using SCWaveFormView, here is a [github link](https://github.com/rFlex/SCWaveformView)

to draw a waveform from an audio file.

My problem is when I run the example code SCWaveFormView works. But when I include this library in my project waveform does not work

Steps I perform to include this library is

1. Copying the SCWaveFormView files, and add in my project
2. Initializing/allocating the waveform and set initial parameters
3. Load the asset/audio file

When I debug all SCWaveFormView code executes correctly, even I can see variable values seem correct.

In SCWaveFormView sample project It works, what should I need to check to work in my project. What could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I do have problem related to file import.

I changed

> lineWidthRatio to 1

or other value and it works for me.